# Powerpoint can't show a video with headers. I see green screen

Tags: ffmpeg, powerpoint, windows-media-player, powerpoint-2016

I've created a video using ffmpeg that contains headers.

My script for creating it is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 560x448 -r 40 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP23_B2.yuv -vcodec rawvideo -qscale 0 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontsize=32: fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf: text='SSIM=0.961': x=(w-tw)/2: y=(lh/2): fontcolor=orange, drawtext=fontsize=22: fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf: text='Bitrate≤1800 [1873 kbps], Frame rate≥40 [43.98 fps]': x=(w-tw)/2: y=(lh/2+30): fontcolor=orange : box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099, drawbox=x=80:y=160:w=220:h=135:color=red@0.5" C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP23_B2_new.avi
```

Firstly, media player showed it as green screen. I downloaded 
`Media Player Codec Pack` and now show its correclty.

However, when I insert it in `powerpoint 2016` I have the same problem of green screen. Do you know how to fix this?

`vlc` player can play it correctly. Is there any way to change the player of excel and use vlc player instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the solution provided here and I solved my problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291879/how-to-play-media-clips-in-powerpoint-by-using-windows-media-player

I embed `windows media player` in my `powerpoint` and I can play the video.

Answer (score 1):

You're outputting an uncompressed stream. Use a codec instead.

```
ffmpeg.exe -f rawvideo -s 560x448 -framerate 40 -pix_fmt yuv420p
  -i C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP23_B2.yuv
  -filter_complex "drawtext=fontsize=32: fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf: text='SSIM=0.961': x=(w-tw)/2: y=(lh/2): fontcolor=orange, drawtext=fontsize=22: fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf: text='Bitrate≤1800 [1873 kbps], Frame rate≥40 [43.98 fps]': x=(w-tw)/2: y=(lh/2+30): fontcolor=orange : box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099,
                   drawbox=x=80:y=160:w=220:h=135:color=red@0.5"
  -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 5 C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP23_B2_new.avi
```

Comment: Will this codec affect the quality of the perceived video?

Comment: Since I use this to evaluate the quality of the video, rawvideo codec is a safe option

Comment: Subjectively, no. Mathematically, yes.

Comment: I tried it and even though now is playing, the video quality is not the same. Since I want to show some results from my phd viva, I can't use `mpeg4` encoder. Any other option please?

Comment: H264 in MP4. `-c:v libx264 -crf 10 out.mp4`

Comment: Using `mp4`, the quality is very poor unfortunately.